# AWS Lambda Bigquery Storage Module Import Issue

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am facing following issue when I try to import Bigquey_storage module in Lambda.

> "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/opt/python/grpc/_cython/**init**.py)",
> "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"

I have created the layer with the same Python runtime as in my lambda. I am using python 3.9 for my lambda and the layer. I tried installing grpcio module explicitly in the layer package. But it did not help.

Prior to this I created Google Cloud Big Query package, and it worked just fine.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, it was suggested in a post to use the same OS to create the layer, that is used for lambda runtime. If you look at lambda runtimes, you can see that OS used in the runtimes is either Amazon Linux or Amazon Linux 2.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html] (Lambda Runtimes).

So, I created a Virtual Machine with Amazon Linux 2 image and created the layer package on that machine. Now it works perfectly in the Lambda Function. I hope this helps.